# Why is .insert not adding entry text into array (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

This part of my code is the problem: I want to add names to Name_List by entering text into the entry widget. Then use the "add" button to insert the item into Name_List by the function add_name.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

Name_List = []

...

class NamePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        name=StringVar()
        name_entry= tk.Entry(self, text="Enter name:", textvariable=name)
        name_entry.pack()
        add_button= tk.Button(self, text="Add",
                              command=lambda: self.add_name(name))
        add_button.pack()
        To_Role_List= tk.Button(self, text="Assign Roles",
                                command=lambda: self.print_namelist())
        To_Role_List.pack()

    def add_name(self,name,i=0):
        Name_List.insert(i, name)
        print(Name_List)
        i+=1

    def print_namelist(self):
        for i in [0,len(Name_List)]:
            print (Name_List[i])


app=TOS_outline()
app.mainloop()
```

My result, after entering the name "Alpha" into the Entry widget, appears to be this (using print of course):

```
[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x03E7D650>]
```

What do I need to change/fix?

Comment: The indentation is broken in the code in your question

Comment: Hi Bryan, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a python list, dont use a counter or range like:

> ```
> def add_name(self,name,i=0):
>     Name_List.insert(i, name)
>     print(Name_List)
>     i+=1
>
> def print_namelist(self):
>     for i in [0,len(Name_List)]:
>         print (Name_List[i])
> ```

instead use:

> ```
> def add_name(self,name):
>     Name_List.append(name)
>     print(Name_List)
>
> def print_namelist(self):
>     for name in Name_List:
>         print (name)
> ```

And use get() to obtain the value of the StringVar object

> ```
> nombre = StringVar() 
> id_art = IntVar()  
> nombre.set("Python para impacientes") 
> id_art.set(1)  
> blog = ttk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=nombre, width=25) 
> arti = ttk.Label(ventana, textvariable=id_art) 
> print('Blog:', nombre.get()) 
> print('Id artículo:', id_art.get())
> ```

Example from: http://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com.es/2016/02/variables-de-control-en-tkinter.html (Spanish)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same response: ['']

Comment: name was declared on __ init __ func and doesnt exists anymore out. Try add_button= tk.Button(self, text="Add",
                              command=lambda: self.add_name(name.get()))

Comment: I still get a [''] when I print the list

Comment: Edit: I figured out the problem. You were right, but it was something else in my code (that was in the ...) causing the problem.

I had app.Tk() and app.TOS_outline. After I deleted app.Tk() and moved app.TOS_outline to a different spot, I got the program to work

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the variable to `.insert` instead of its value. `Name_List.insert(i, name)` must be `Name_List.insert(i, name.get())`.

Comment: I changed it. Now all I get is:  ['']